# Guice - Inject object with two different implementations

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, guice

First I have to say that I tried googling the answer to this question, but no answer explained my doubts.
Anyway,
What I'm trying to understand is the following:

```
public interface Animal{
 public void makeSound(int times);
}
```

This interface has two different implementations:

```
public class Cat implements Animal{
 @Override
 public void makeSound(int times){
   for(int=0;i<times;i++){ 
      this.meow();
   }
 }
}

public class Dog implements Animal{
 @Override
 public void makeSound(int times){
   for(int=0;i<times;i++){ 
      this.wolf();
   }
  }
}
```

I will be using those implementations as in the following example:

```
public class AnimalStateManager {

 @Inject
 private Animal animal;

 public void makeAnimalAct(){
   animal.makeSound(100)
 }

}
```

**UPDATE 1.1 TO THE POST**

And I have one more class using the same "Animal" interface:

```
 public class AnimalMakeSoundOnce {

     @Inject
     private Animal animal;

     public void makeSoundOnce(){
       animal.makeSound(1)
     }

    }
```

So my question would be:
1- How I can know what implementation is going to be injected to the AnimalStateManager?
2- What if I wanted to force the "animal" object on the "AnimalStateManager" to be a cat?

**UPDATE 1.1 TO THE POST**
3- What if I want to make the AnimalMakeSoundOnce uses the Dog implementation and the AnimalStateManager uses the Cat implementation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Guice you have to implement a module (override the `AbstractModule` class) and bind Animal to the specific implementation class.
To answer your questions:

1. You can of course call `animal.getClass()` to check at runtime which implementation class was injected. But this would break the prinziple of IOC where it does not matter which specific implementation you use.
2. To force `animal` in your `AnimalStateManager` be cat you have to write your own Module.

   ```
   public class AnimalStateModule extends AbstractModule {

       @Override
       protected void configure() {
           bind(Animal.class).to(Cat.class);
       }
   }
   ```

And to instantiate the AnimalState:

```
Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new AnimalStateModule());
final AnimalStateManager ass = inj.getInstance(AnimalStateManager.class);
ass.makeAnimalAct(); // will cause a call to Cat.meow()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the clear answer, can you please take a look on the update i made on the post and tell if you help with that? 10x

Answer (score 0):

I think another important question is how you're going to be using both the MakeSound and MakeSoundOnce objects.  Within the same module created above, there are a number of ways in order to specify which type you want, both of which are a method of binding annotations described (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations):

1) You can use the @Named annotation provided by Guice.  You'd have something that looks like the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Animal.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Cat")).to(Cat.class);
    bind(Animal.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Dog")).to(Dog.class);
}
```

which would then be used with:

```
@Inject @Named("Cat") private Animal animal;
```

within your *MakeSound classes.

2) You can also create your own annotation (described in the same link above with pretty good detail) which would give you the option to use:

```
@Inject @Cat private Animal animal;
```

within your *MakeSound classes.  Most of the time we stick with the @Named annotation, due to it not requiring the extra Annotation interface to be created.

Will the *MakeSound classes be implementing by Injection?  And will you ever need to switch the Dog/Cat implementations within the *MakeSound classes that you've described (ie. want to have a cat only meow once, and vice versa)?